# null values submitted to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, variables, authentication, submit

I am trying to make a user system for my website but having some trouble with submitting it.  It always submit a 0 to the database for everything.  I have read on w3schools about global and local variables and I think this may be my problem but I don't know for sure.
Heres my code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect(localhost, 262096, 9201999);
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("262096", $con);
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordconf = $_POST['passwordconf'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$securityq = $_POST['securityq'];
$qanswer = $_POST['qanswer'];

if(!isset($firstname) || !isset($lastname) || !isset($username) || !isset($password) || !isset($passwordconf) || !isset($email) || !isset($securityq) || !isset($qanswer))
    {
    echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
    }

$uname = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
$unamequery = mysql_query($uname) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($unamequery) > 0) 
    {
    echo "The username you entered is already taken";
    }

$emailfind = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";
$emailquery = mysql_query($emailfind) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($emailquery) > 0)
    {
    echo "The email you entered is already registered";
    }

if($password != $passwordconf)
    {
    echo "The passwords you entered do not match";
    }

$regex = "/^[a-z0-9]+([_.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+.[a-z]{2,}$/i";
if(!preg_match($regex, $email))
    {
    echo "The email you entered is not in name@domain format";
    }

else
    {
    $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $hpassword = crypt($password,$salt);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password, email, securityq, qanswer, salt)
    VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$username','$hpassword','$email','$securityq','$qanswer','$salt')";
    mysql_query($insert);


    if(!mysql_query($insert))
        {
        die('Could not submit');
        }
    else
        {
        echo "Information was submited.  Please check your email for confirmation";
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Please don't use W3schools see [why](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with global and local variables? They only matter inside functions, and you don't have any functions. Anyway, what does `var_dump($insert)` show?

Comment: what do you mean? var_dump($insert)?

Comment: have you already tried `echo $insert;` to watch it?

Comment: this is what is showsThe username you entered is already takenThe email you entered is already registeredInformation was submited. Please check your email for confirmationINSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password, email, securityq, qanswer, salt) VALUES ('admin','admin','admin','TJNlw6CQlDM','admin@admin.com','admin','admin','&OAEÉý¾õÿá¾FV) >½’äü‰ˆ]=ª=Ú#')

Comment: @TravisNabbefeld I think, my answer can solve your problem

Comment: it showed me this - The username you entered is already takenThe email you entered is already registeredInformation was submited. Please check your email for confirmationINSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, password, email, securityq, qanswer, salt) VALUES ('admin','admin','admin','TJNlw6CQlDM','admin@admin.com','admin','admin','&OAEÉý‌​¾õÿá¾FV) >½’äü‰ˆ]=ª=Ú#')

Comment: @TravisNabbefeld your hash is not escaped. Have you really escaped all fields?

Comment: what? i don't know what you talking about, could you please explain?

Comment: See the answer, please. Escaping is `$salt  = mysql_real_escape_string($salt);` You should escape all your variables before this line "$insert = "INSERT..."

Comment: so is that the problem that im using depreciated functions?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer.

First of all, I agree with advice to move to PDO. mysql_* functions are deprecated. But if you wish to use it, escape every variable directly **before** sql due to **'**-symbols in your sql:

```
$hpassword  = mysql_real_escape_string($hpassword );
```

As for me, the following syntax is easier to view rather than insert ... values():

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `users` 
    SET `firstname` = '$firstname',
    SET `hpassword` = '$hpassword'..."
```

Actually, I am trying to forgot this kind of code. I use PDO or comfortable uniDB class for simple apps.

Is it correct behaviour that it inserts user no matter errors like matching password? You should fix conditions.

Your conditions logic is wrong. You submit after `if(!preg_match($regex, $email))`. So if email is correct, it submits. Fix it as follows using ELSEIF

```
$regex = "/^[a-z0-9]+([_.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+.[a-z]{2,}$/i";

if(mysql_num_rows($emailquery) > 0){
    echo "The email you entered is already registered";
}elseif($password != $passwordconf){
    echo "The passwords you entered do not match";
}elseif(!preg_match($regex, $email))
{
    echo "The email you entered is not in name@domain format";
}else{
    // insertion code HERE
}
```

Comment: When using uniDB class I just write `uniDB::insert("INSERT INTO users SET firstname= '?s'", $firtname);`
It escapes variables by itself and it is convenient to use placements.

Comment: no it not. i dont no why it does that. i have all the errors in if's and submitting it in an else

Comment: See the updated unswer. Summary you have 2 errors - in logic and in sql.